# send running process argument

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, process

I have IE run on my system , I would like to send it an url.

I would like to know how should I find the running IE proccess and how should I send it the Url

I will need to send the Url to the Running IE process

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

It will open it up with the default browser.

[Documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx)

Comment: It is not good I will need to send the URL to a running IE proccess

Comment: This will open up in IE if it is already running. I tried this.